# How to escape a # in velocity

Tags: velocity

I would like to know how can i escape a # in velocity. Backslash seems to escape it but it prints itself as well

This:

```
\#\#
```

prints:

```
\#\#
```

I would like:

```
##
```

Comment: Note that as of 2012 at least, you can now escape things in Velocity with backslash: \# and \$. See http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Getting_literal

Comment: see also http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html chapter "Escaping VTL Directives"

Answer (score 88):

This:

```
#[[
##
]]#
```

Will yield:

```
##
```

Anything within `#[[ ... ]]#` is not parsed.

Documentation of [don't parse me block](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#literals) is at the end of literal section.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! The above code generates `\n##\n` though, so just use `#[[##]]#` if you don't want empty lines before and after the `##`.

Answer (score 51):

If you don't want to bother with the EscapeTool, you can do this:

```
#set( $H = '#' )
$H$H
```

Comment: That's what I used when I needed it, the escape tool is kind of clunky

Comment: I think this always works, unrelated with versions of velocity.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe, the following site helps? http://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/EscapeTool.html

Comment: Thomas, can you tell me where the toolbox configuration goes?

Answer (score 3):

Add the esc tool to your toolbox and then you can use ${esc.hash}

Answer (score 2):

${esc.h} will output # as per

[this link](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/EscapeTool.html)

Answer (score 0):

The set technique is a good way to get around any characters you need escaping, like if you want to have $name followed by "_lastname" then you can do:

```
set ($n = '_lastname)
```

and have this in your template:

```
$name$n
```

and it's all good.