# Velocity parser crashes when parsing java code template

Tags: java, velocity

When trying to use a java source code as template for Velocity, it crashes at this line of the template:

```
/*  @see panama.form.Validator#validate(java.lang.Object) */
```

with this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Lexical error,   Encountered: "l" (108), after : "." at *unset*[line 23, column 53]
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.evaluate(RuntimeInstance.java:1301)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.evaluate(RuntimeInstance.java:1265)
at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.evaluate(VelocityEngine.java:199)
```

Apparently it takes the `#validate` for a macro and crashes when it tries to parse the arguments for the macro. Is there anything one could do about this?

I'm using Velocity 1.7.

**Edit**

I know I could escape the `#` characters in the template files, but there are quite a number of them which also might change now and then, so I would prefer a way that would not require manual changes on the files.

Comment: Oddly this only happens on Windows for me, works find on unix,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First option**
Try this  solution from here: [Escaping VTL Directives](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escaping_vtl_directives)

VTL directives can be escaped with the backslash character ("\") in a manner similar to valid VTL references.

```
## #include( "a.txt" ) renders as <contents of a.txt>
#include( "a.txt" )

## \#include( "a.txt" ) renders as #include( "a.txt" )
\#include( "a.txt" )

## \\#include ( "a.txt" ) renders as \<contents of a.txt>
\\#include ( "a.txt" )
```

**Second option** 
You have this tool `[EscapeTool][2]`. 
Tool for working with escaping in Velocity templates.

It provides methods to **escape outputs for Java**, JavaScript, HTML, XML and SQL. **Also provides methods to render VTL characters that otherwise needs escaping**.

**Third option**: 
You may also try this workaround, I didn't use it but it should work:

You can at the beginning read your template as a `String` and then **pre-parse** it. For example replace all `#` with `\#`, or add to the beginning of file

```
  #set( $H = '#' )
  $H$H
```

see this answer: [How to escape a # in velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744/how-to-escape-a-in-velocity)  And then from that **pre-parsed**  `String` create Template by using this answer: [How to use String as Velocity Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432468/how-to-use-string-as-velocity-template)

Comment: Thanks, but please see my edit to the question -- I'd rather a solution that does not require manual changes to the files.

Comment: I know that tool but that's not what I need, because Velocity crashes already when reading the template.

Comment: Updated my answer again :)

Comment: I ended up with the pre-parsing idea myself already but thanks for the hint on escaping the # using backslash - I hadn't thought about that and used {HASH} :-) -- as there are no other answers I guess there is not better way than that and accept your answer. Btw. one has to post-parse the merged template again and remove the escape again.

Comment: glad that it was helpful :)